# element.dispatchEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, element, attachevent

I wrote a plugin , but whene Active ,disable Editor and in firebug Mozila below error Is shown

```
element.dispatchEvent is not a function   prototype.js:5457

and line 5457 prototype.js
  if (document.createEvent)
  5457:  element.dispatchEvent(event);
  else
  element.fireEvent(event.eventType, event);

  return Event.extend(event);
  }
```

but plugin work very good but disable Editor.
    What is the cause؟

Comment: Your title says **`attachEvent`** is not a function; your text says **`dispatchEvent`** is not a function. Which is the real error?

Answer (score 2):

Its cause the variable element has no function `dispatchEvent`. So you should check that element in this case is the one you expect, I doubt it. Probably you pass null/undefined or any other object but not a DOM element to this function.